# Is there a way to specify multiple SQL Server 2008 Schemas for Liquibase's 'generateChangeLog' command?

Tags: sql-server-2008, liquibase

I currently have a batch file with the following contents to generate the Liquibase change log from my already existing database's tables and stored procedures:

```
@echo off
liquibase --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog1.xml --defaultSchemaName="schExampleSchema1" generateChangeLog
liquibase --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog2.xml --defaultSchemaName="schExampleSchema2" generateChangeLog
exit
```

Instead of having separate files for each schema is their a way for the Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' command to generate all change log information for more than 1 schema in a single command.

I already tried doing a comma separated list but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately generateChangeLog supports only one schema at a time currently.

Comment: is this still true ?