# Can Liquibase handle multiple schemas managed by the same application?

Tags: schema, liquibase

We are developing an application which uses multiple schemas to manage database objects. 
I cannot see anyway of doing this with Liquibase. 
I had to drop schemas manually and create them.

dropAll gradle task only drops objects in public schema.
Any help would be great.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended to record all liquibase changesets in one database when managing multiple databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211365/recommended-to-record-all-liquibase-changesets-in-one-database-when-managing-mul)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338430/is-there-a-way-to-specify-multiple-sql-server-2008-schemas-for-liquibases-gene and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406996/liquidbase-with-multiple-schemas

Comment: If your application has multiple schemas, shouldn't each be managed separately? (Run liquibase once for each schema) I resist pressures to split my application's schema unless an application component is truly stand-alone. The modern trend towards microservices is a good example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase can handle objects within multiple schemas and can also manage creating additional schemas as well.

When you connect to the database, Liquibase will create a DATABASECHANGELOG table in the default schema and that schema needs to exist. That table tracks which changeSets have executed, and anything that can be done through SQL can be done within your changeSets.

There are built-in tags for things like createTable, addColumn etc which will make changes in the default schema, but they all have tags such as tableSchemaName that can be used to target the object to a different schema.

If you want to make changes for which there are not built-in tags, you can always use the "sql" tag and specify whatever sql you want, such as `create database additional_info`

Comment: bear in mind that permissions of the current database connection user may prevent from creating objects in another schema.